# What Swift property types are allowed in UIApperance compliant custom classes?

Tags: ios, swift, uiappearance

I recently tried with no success to add a `UIApperance` compliant property to one of my Swift classes (`ScoreView`). You can see the relevant code below:

```
private var gaugeThresholds = Array<GaugeThreshold?>(repeating: nil, count: ScoreView.maxGaugeIntervals)

public func gaugeThreshold(forInterval interval: Int) -> GaugeThreshold? {
    return (0 <= interval && interval < ScoreView.maxGaugeIntervals) ? self.gaugeThresholds[interval] : nil
}

public func setGaugeThreshold(_ threshold: GaugeThreshold, forInterval interval: Int) {
    if 0 <= interval && interval < ScoreView.maxGaugeIntervals {
        self.gaugeThresholds[interval] = threshold
    }
}
```

where `GaugeThreshold` is a Swift struct:

```
public struct GaugeThreshold {
    let until: Float
    let color: UIColor

    public init(until: Float, color: UIColor) {
        self.until = until
        self.color = color
    }
}
```

This was failing miserably, and the only reason I can think of for this to fail is the fact that I'm using a custom type for the property instead of one of the *standard types*.

According to `UIAppearanceContainer` documentation: The property type may be any standard iOS type: `id`, `NSInteger`, `NSUInteger`, `CGFloat`, `CGPoint`, `CGSize`, `CGRect`, `UIEdgeInsets` or `UIOffset`. But if you browse the [list of methods and properties conforming to `UIAppearance` as of iOS 8.0](https://gist.github.com/mattt/5135521), you can see there are other types that are working properly as `UIImage`, `UIColor`... so does anybody know what makes a type valid for being used as a `UIAppearance` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, nothing like posting to StackOverflow to find out the answer five minutes later. It turns out the key is the `id` type. Changing

```
public struct GaugeThreshold { ...
```

to

```
public class GaugeThreshold: NSObject { ...
```

did the trick.